# Unable to Mock System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, testng, powermockito

I am writing unit tests using TestNG. The problem is when I mock System.currentTimeMillis, it returns the actual value instead of the mocked one. Ideally, it should return 0L , but it returns  the actual value. What should I do to proceed?

```
class MyClass{

    public void func1(){
       System.out.println("Inside func1");
       func2();
    }

    private void func2(){
        int maxWaitTime = (int)TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + maxWaitTime; // Mocking not happening
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
                System.out.println("Inside func2");
        }
    }
}
```

```
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
class MyClassTest extends PowerMockTestCase{
   private MyClass myClass;
   
   @BeforeMethod
   public void setup() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     myclass = new MyClass();
   }
   @Test    
   public void func1Test(){
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class)
      PowerMockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(0L);
      myclass.func1();
   }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001671/override-java-system-currenttimemillis-for-testing-time-sensitive-code

Answer (score 6):

Make a package constructor that you can pass in a `java.time.Clock`

```
class MyClass{ 
    private Clock clock;
    public MyClass() {
        this.clock = Clock.systemUTC();
    } 
    // for tests 
    MyClass(Clock c) {
        this.clock = c;
   }
```

Then mock that for tests, and use `this.clock.instant()` to get the clock's time

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the annotation `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` to the class `MyClassTest`.

Nevertheless, I would advise to refactor the code to use `java.time.Clock`, instead of mocking.

Comment: Are you sure @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) should be used with TestNG, because I'm getting an error.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `PowerMock`, you can use `Mockito` which also has a `mockStatic` method

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67061112/5050667) for an example with `LocalDate`

Here is how it would look like in your case

```
try(MockedStatic<System> mock = Mockito.mockStatic(System.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
    doReturn(0L).when(mock).currentTimeMillis();
    // Put the execution of the test inside of the try, otherwise it won't work
}
```

Notice the usage of `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` which will guarantee that whenever `System` is invoked with another method, it will execute the real method of the class

Comment: MockedStatic is not available. Intellij is unable to import any such class

Comment: It's not recommended to depend on actual system time in tests, especially when dealing with timezones

Comment: @OneCricketeer But I have to. It's not possible on my end to change the actual code

Comment: @DawsonSmith you should use `Mockito` for this

Comment: @YassinHajaj But how? is it present in TestNG?

Comment: No, you can add the dependency, I just added it in  the post

Comment: This would be awesome, but unfortunately `MockedStatic` does not allow mocking `System` methods as you will get a `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: It is not possible to mock static methods of java.lang.System to avoid interfering with class loading what leads to infinite loops`. See [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013#issuecomment-666994541) for the rationale.